# Error while adding VHD as OS Disk in resource manager

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-disk

I am trying to create VM using existing VHD which I have on the storage blob.
I ran the below command

Add-AzureDisk -DiskName "Keldc1" -MediaLocation "https://*****.blob.core.windows.net/essrestore/Kel-DC01201611012647.vhd" -Label "Bootdisk" -OS "Windows"

the error i reeived is

Add-AzureDisk : BadRequest: The storage account with the name ***** as specified in the VHD URI 
https://*****.blob.core.windows.net/essrestore/Kel-DC01201611012647.vhd does not exists in the current subscription

I verified I have the subscription is correct and the Storage account is in the same subscription.

Help Please.

Answer (score 1):

You probably created Your resources in the new portal, however You could be executing commands on the classic one. Try this,

```
azure login
azure config mode arm
```

This will execute the commands on the new portal.

Answer (score 0):

Check with the

```
Get-AzureSubscription -Current
```

the current subscription. If that is different from the subscription you are going to use for your disk, use

```
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId "id"
```

and execute the commandlet again.
Basically, it checks if there is the storage account specified in your string in the currently used Azure account, and if not, throws the error.
Just checked - it should work if the right subscription is selected and there is the storage account in that.